# Bellman-Ford or Network Flow for findin maximum number of distinct path?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, bellman-ford, network-flow

We have a directed Graph (without weights), G(V, E), with two vertex `s` and `t` such that in-degree of `s` and out-degree of `t` are equals to `0`. we want to find maximum number of distinct-edges paths  from `s` to `t`. by using which algorithm we can do this. Bellman-Ford, Dijkestra, Huffman and Network Flow. I think Huffman so irrelevant,  but how about others? I think  Network Flow is the answer, but I have no idea why? stackeeeers, please help me!

Comment: What makes two paths distinct? If they have no edges in common, or must they also have no nodes in common?

Comment: (Either way, Network Flow is the answer, but edge-disjoint only is more obvious.)

Comment: @IVlad, now, it's okey, see edits.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, okey now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Network Flow. It even [tells you how on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem):

> Maximum edge-disjoint path
>
> Given a directed graph G = (V, E) and two vertices s and t, we are to find the maximum number of edge-disjoint paths from s to t. This problem can be transformed to a maximum flow problem by constructing a network N = (V, E) from G with s and t being the source and the sink of N respectively and assign each edge with unit capacity.

The intuition behind this is that the maximum flow algorithms basically solve your problem while finding the augmenting paths. What an augmenting path is is best explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397118/graph-what-exactly-is-augmenting-paths) I think, by [Ivaylo Strandjev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812912/ivaylo-strandjev):

> An augmenting path is a simple path - a path that does not contain cycles - through the graph using only edges with positive capacity from the source to the sink. So the statement above is somehow obvious - if you can not find a path from the source to the sink that only uses positive capacity edges, then the flow can not be increased(by the way the proof of that statement is not that easy).

Comment: is it possible to add a bit for "augmenting paths", I Google it but didn't understand.

Comment: @HouraAsali I couldn't explain it any better than the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397118/graph-what-exactly-is-augmenting-paths

Comment: @HouraAsali Bellman Ford is used for finding shortest paths in weighted graphs. First of all, your question deals with an unweighted graph. Second, Bellman Ford, by itself, cannot count the number of paths.

Comment: wow, I learn it..., my last question is you wrote" This problem can be transformed to a maximum flow problem by ...." okey and want to find which? is it possible to make it clearer?

Comment: @HouraAsali - it's the classical max flow problem. Find the max flow from `s` to `t` if all edges have capacity `1`.