# What does it mean to augment flow?

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-flow, edmonds-karp

When the Edmonds-Karp algorithm says to augment flow f along path p, what does it actually mean to augment the flow? Does it mean to send the flow along the path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [graph - What exactly is Augmenting Paths?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397118/graph-what-exactly-is-augmenting-paths)

Comment: @SamSegers I've saw that but I don't think it's the same thing. Is augmenting paths the same as augmenting flow?

Comment: You augment the flow after finding an augmenting path. Because if you can find such a path, where flow can be added from source to sink at each edge, this means the total flow can at least be augmented with that amount.